# How to Add multiple Cells if they have an formula in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Needed help with adding cells with formuala in it

You can check the image out for better understand
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLH9x.jpg

Comment: what do you mean "with formula in it"? Do you mean cells J6 to J15 have formulas in them? If that's what you mean, then your `SUM` is correct. The reason why you don't see a non-zero result is probably because those formulas are not returning numeric results. For example, if J6 contains formula `="227"` then it won't be summed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Text turn value？

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--J6:J15)
```

....